# How to use Pre tag to restrict word break in HTML

Tags: html, css, pre

I'm using a <pre> tag in my design. The thing is my pre even breaks the words at the end of the line. Say I'm at the end of the line and if there is a large word then it breaks it. For example at the end of the line we have a large word say STACKOVERFLOW.
So my pre tag display the word STACKOVERFLOW as:

```
STAC
KOVERFLOW
```

Where as it should show the whole word in the new line.
Following is my code for pre tag:

```css
pre{
        white-space: pre-wrap;
        word-wrap: break-word; 
    }
```

**Following is my HTML Code:**

```html
<div uib-carousel active="active" class="text-primary">
  <div uib-slide index="$index" class="uibSlider" ng-repeat='summary in desc'>
<pre class="text-justify">{{summary.info}}</pre>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you try removing word-wrap property?

Comment: Seems fine to me http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GrLGYj

Comment: Yeah even If I remove, it doesn't make any difference. It works in code pen, but I don't understand why does the same code doesn't work at my side.

Comment: If you post a minimal working code snippet reproducing the issue, which you are supposed to, we will be able to help, anything less, and we're all guessing until someone gets lucky

Comment: So, for styling this is the only thing I'm using. I can show my html code also. I'm using a carousal. and I'm trying to insert a pre tag inside a carousal. I dont' know if this is creating a problem.

Comment: I've updated my question

Comment: Hmm, what does `text-primary` class do? .. what does `text-justify` class do? ... We need a **minimal working code snippet reproducing the issue**, not a couple of tags and 1 CSS rule

Comment: I'm new to this field I don't understand this sentence: **minimal working code snippet reproducing the issue** I apologize, but what does this mean, The text primary changes the text color to blue it is a bootstrap class and text-justify is also a bootstrap class which displays the description in order.

Comment: Please read here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ... short version, you need to post enough code so we can actual _see_ how it behaves, then we will be able to tell what is wrong ... as of now, the small code fragment you gave us works as expected, which kind of prove my point

Comment: This is the complete code which I shared. I think the problem is with my visual studio, because when i try to post the same code in Plunker or Code Pen it works as I expect it to work. But using visual studio when I run  it, it is creating the problem.

Comment: Can you point to a website where this happens then?

Comment: So, the thing is my web application is not published yet. It is a simple project. I can show you the output though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [w3 specification for the `word-wrap` property](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#white-space-property):

> **‘break-word’**
> An unbreakable "word" may be broken at an arbitrary point if there are no otherwise-acceptable break points in the line. Shaping characters are still shaped as if the word were not broken, and grapheme clusters must together stay as one unit. No hyphenation character is inserted at the break point.

Because you're using the 'break-word' rule, this means that your long words will be broken if there is no width left in the container and if there are no other more acceptable break points.

Instead try using the 'normal' rule:

> **‘normal’**
> Lines may break only at allowed break points. However, the restrictions introduced by ‘word-break: keep-all’ may be relaxed to match ‘word-break: normal’ if there are no otherwise-acceptable break points in the line.

Comment: The thing is I need a line break at certain position such as at a new point. But what my code is doing is it is working as expected to start at new line but at the large word it breaks it, I don't want that to happen.

Comment: If I make it to normal it is not doing anything for me.

Answer (score 2):

`break-word` means that you want the word to break.
Does the following work for you?

```
pre {
   white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Comment: It is still showing me the same result. This thing works when i try in Codepen and Plunker. But the same thing doesn't work on my side. Is it because I'm using pre tag directly. Or should I use paragraph tag and keep class name as pre?

Comment: You should be able to style pre as you please. Which browser are you testing in? Would adding a `!important` to the declaration force it to work? You should be able to see if `pre-wrap` is being overridden using your inspector tools

Comment: Sure I will try it, i'm using Chrome and where can I use !important?

Comment: It would be `pre { white-space: pre-wrap !important;} `

Comment: Browsers normally render the `pre` tag with white space intact and no word-wrapping, ie. by default no breaking till it sees a `<br>` tag Strange you are seeing it differently :/

Comment: It works at the inspect tools but while displaying it does not display as we are expecting. i'm placing this pre tag in a div, dies this make a difference?

Comment: can you post the text you are working with and I'll see if I can recreate the problem?

Comment: So, you want me to show you the text which is rendered on the browser?

Comment: So, following is the sentence, which is breaking between **stackoverflow**   I'm using pre-tag in my design. The thing is my pre-tag even breaks the words at the end of the line. Say I'm at the end of the line and If I there is a large word then it breaks it. For example at the end of the line we have a large word say STACKOVERFlOWI'm using psre-tag in my design. Thesaw thing is my pre-tag even breaks the words at the end of the line. Say I'm at the end of the line and If I there is a large word then it breaks it. For example at the end of the line we have a large word saysa STACKOVERFlOW

Comment: When I try your code in CodePen it works but it doesn't work at my side. I'm using this pre tag inside a carousal.. Does it make any difference.